# Can't find out component in decompiled APK

Tags: android, decompiling

I try to use Wear OS device paired with IOS device and got an error ([link to community question](https://support.google.com/wearos/thread/191124412/strange-error-apears-when-using-watch-with-ios)) TLDR: ru.nspk.wallet.core.data.model.registration.certificate.DeviceLocaleModel component call exception. This exception is only called with IOS device (instead of android) So I try to find out code place where value is requested to find out how to fix it.
I was try to use jadx and apktool but I cant found nothing related to error. May be I use this tools in wrong way, may be there is a silver bullet app to decompile apk packages

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded MirPay.apk and decompiled it.
classes.dex is only 3kb and indeed does not contain any useful information.
All the information regarding classes is encrypted in \assets\classesX.dat files.

I tried to find which tool can decrypt .dat file and apparently there is no tool exist:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/util-nov-24-2022-apktool-tool-for-reverse-engineering-apk-files.1755243/page-292#post-80568101

If you look to the description of the exception:

```
 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: country is blank
```

Assuming that some function has argument - country. And MirPay app gets that argument from IOS device. Since apple banned wireless payments in Russia, either it is intended "bug" on IOS side or just a bug that no one would fix in Apple.

You definitely should get in touch with MirPay devs so they will find some workaround.

Comment: i searched a bit and found that MirPay on wear OS can work regardless on connected devices. Have you tried to install MirPay on your watch without  connecting to IOS/android device and use it? And only after purchases succeeded, connect the watch with apple device?

Comment: https://androidinsider.ru/polezno-znat/kak-ustanovit-mir-pay-na-wear-os-i-platit-beskontaktno-v-rossii.html

Comment: Google ban wireless payments in RU too, but app still working on wear OS device paired with android smarthones also you wrote 'Have you tried to install MirPay on your watch without connecting to IOS/android device and use it?' How to install app to unpaired wear os device? I thought this class of device can't do anything without pairing.